# Is monodromy a special case of holonomy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fiber-bundles, holonomy

Is monodromy a special case of holonomy? Is it just a difference in language in different settings?

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95939/what-is-the-difference-between-holonomy-and-monodromy) might be useful.

Comment: Please first state your definitions of "holonomy" and of "monodromy".

Comment: I WOULD HAPPY TO HAVE RESPONSES THAT STATE THEIR FAVORITE DEFINITiONS.  The setting of smooth vector bundles over smooth manifolds would be fine but if you prefer a different cat...

Comment: I suggest you read the linked Mathoverflow answer and if it is insufficient, ask for a clarification here or there. Currently, the MO answer has 89 upvotes, I doubt you will find a better answer here...